# Erro de sintaxe ao testar a query no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Erro resolvido .

### Query

```
SELECT i.codiniciativa,
    te.nome as nome_tema,
    te.codtemaestrategico as cod_te,
    p.observacoes as per_obs,
    te.sequencia as tem_sequencia,
    p.sigla as per_sigla,
    p.nome as nome_perspectiva,
    p.codperspectiva as cod_perspectiva,
    o.sequencia as sequencia_obj,
    o.codobjetivo as cod_obj,
    o.nome as nome_obj,concat(p.sigla, ' ', te.sequencia,
    '.', o.sequencia, '.',i.sequencia) as codigo,i.nome as nom_iniciativa,
    i.sequencia as iniciativa_sequencia,
    i.metas,i.responsavel,i.indicadores,
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes1']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) < ".$_parametros['mes1']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes1']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '01',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes2']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) < ".$_parametros['mes2']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes2']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '02',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes3']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) < ".$_parametros['mes3']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes3']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '03',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes4']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) < ".$_parametros['mes4']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes4']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '04',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes5']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) < ".$_parametros['mes5']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes5']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '05',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = $ano AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes6']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= $ano AND month(a.data) <".$_parametros['mes6']." AND curdate() >= '$ano-".$_parametros['mes6']."-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '06' 
    FROM $_base.perspectivas p  
    LEFT JOIN $_base.temasestrategicos te ON p.codperspectiva = te.codperspectiva 
    LEFT JOIN $_base.objetivos o ON te.codtemaestrategico = o.codtemaestrategico 
    LEFT JOIN $_base.iniciativas i ON o.codobjetivo = i.codobjetivo 
    WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' AND p.status = 'A' AND te.status = 'A' AND o.status = 'A' AND i.status = 'A'ORDER BY p.sequencia ASC,te.sequencia ASC,
    o.sequencia ASC,CAST(i.sequencia AS DECIMAL) ASC"
```

Estou tentando encontrar o erro mas não estou conseguindo: Por favor, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato! Abraços.

Query atualizada para o phpmyadmin

```
SELECT i.codiniciativa,
    te.nome as nome_tema,
    te.codtemaestrategico as cod_te,
    p.observacoes as per_obs,
    te.sequencia as tem_sequencia,
    p.sigla as per_sigla,
    p.nome as nome_perspectiva,
    p.codperspectiva as cod_perspectiva,
    o.sequencia as sequencia_obj,
    o.codobjetivo as cod_obj,
    o.nome as nome_obj,concat(p.sigla, ' ', te.sequencia,
    '.', o.sequencia, '.',i.sequencia) as codigo,i.nome as nom_iniciativa,
    i.sequencia as iniciativa_sequencia,
    i.metas,i.responsavel,i.indicadores,
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) = 1 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) <1 AND curdate() >= 2015-1-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '01',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) =2 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) < 2 AND curdate() >= 2015-2-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '02',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) = 3 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) < 3 AND curdate() >=2015-3-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '03',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) = ".$_parametros['mes4']." ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) < 4 AND curdate() >=2015-4-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '04',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) = 5  ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) < 5 AND curdate() >=2015-5-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '05',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2015 AND month(a.data) = 6  ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2015 AND month(a.data) < 6 AND curdate() >= 2015-6-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '06' 
    FROM perspectivas p  
    LEFT JOIN temasestrategicos te ON p.codperspectiva = te.codperspectiva 
    LEFT JOIN objetivos o ON te.codtemaestrategico = o.codtemaestrategico 
    LEFT JOIN .iniciativas i ON o.codobjetivo = i.codobjetivo 
    WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' AND p.status = 'A' AND te.status = 'A' AND o.status = 'A' AND i.status = 'A'ORDER BY p.sequencia ASC,te.sequencia ASC,
    o.sequencia ASC,CAST(i.sequencia AS DECIMAL) ASC
```

Comment: O mais simples é no php vc imprimir o valor dessa variável/query e testar no phpmyAdmin.

Comment: como poderia testa de forma correta o valor dessa variável/query  no phpmyadmin

Comment: Opa, deletei sem querer... trocar essa parte `'$ano-".$_parametros['mes1']."-01'` por isso `"'" . $ano . "-" . $_parametros['mes1'] . "-01" . "'"`

Comment: fiz algumas alterações e tá dando esse erro agora   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM 2015 avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND' at line 1

Comment: Nesse `AND curdate() >= 2015-1-01'`, você não acha que esqueceu do apóstrofo no início da data? Acho que deveria ser `AND curdate() >= '2015-1-01'`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa já corrigir esse erro , só que queria imprimir com php o Financeiro , pois dou echo do ['perspectiva'] ela apenas imprimir o 1 mas quero que imprima o nome Financeiro . Com posso fazer ? <select name="perspectiva"> <option value="1">Financeiro</option> </select>

Comment: @allanaraujo Se você já corrigiu esse erro, edite a pergunta e coloque do jeito que está. Caso contrário, dificilmente alguém reabriria/reabrirá a sua pergunta, vez que nela há um erro de digitação gritante no seu SQL que estraga tudo e que vai pular na frente de qualquer um que queira te ajudar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa já coloquei como resolvido , mas como faço para  imprimir com php o Financeiro , pois dou echo do ['perspectiva'] ela apenas imprimir o 1 mas quero que imprima o nome Financeiro . Com posso fazer ? <select name="perspectiva"> <option value="1">Financeiro</option> </select>

Comment: @allanaraujo Não sei. Na verdade nem entendi o que é que você está perguntando. Sua pergunta é sobre SQL e agora você pergunta algo sobre o financeiro do PHP que não tenho a menor ideia do que seja contendo código HTML. Seja lá o que isso for, seria para fazer uma outra pergunta totalmente diferente (se o sistema te permitir). E só para constar, não negativei e nem votei para fechar sua pergunta, mas não colocaria ela para reabertura também.

Comment: @VictorStafusa já corrigir o erro da query , falta só com o php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O phpMyAdmin não aceita variáveis de PHP, no exemplo você usou: `$_base.avaliacoes`.

Tente realizar: `echo $sua_query;` e teste o resultado no `phpMyAdmin`

Além disso, nas datas está faltando uma aspas simples antes:

mude de:

`curdate() >= 2015-1-01'`

para:

`curdate() >= '2015-1-01'`

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações e está dando esse erro agora #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM 2015 avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND' at line 1

Comment: coloquei no post da pergunta .

Comment: Faltou colocar uma aspas simples no início das DATAs.

Comment: conseguir verificar o erro . Muito Obrigado .

Comment: Como posso fazer o que está no pergunta  ?

Comment: Aqui tá dizendo que só vou poder postar em uma semana .

Comment: Mas me diga como posso fazer com que essa query ao ser buscada no phpmyadmin possar retornar todas as colunas tipo ,quando faço a busca ela só retorna perspectivas, queria que ela retorna-se todas essas outras avaliacoes,iniciativas,objetivos,perspectiva,temasestrategicos,tiposdeavaliacoes

Comment: @allanaraujo o sistema acabou bloqueando você de fazer novas perguntas devido a qualidade, para ter esse privilégio novamente você precisa editar, caprichar na perguntas, [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2222/91)  tem umas dicas de como melhorar. Se tiver alguma dúvida avise ou pode postar uma pergunta no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) que é o local para discussões sobre o stack overflow, problemas com o site ou usuários etc.

Comment: @rray  como posso fazer para o WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5'  aonde é '5' ficar automático para quando selecionar alguma coluna.

Comment: a unica coisa que quero é deixar o WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' que fique no modo dinâmico , tipo quando selecionar uma das 8 perspectiva ela selecione de forma automatica no  WHERE p.codperspectiva = ''

Comment: esta dando esse erro  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /var/www/PlanejamentoEstrategico/model/indoperacionais/Indoperacionais.php on line 74

Comment: @AllanAndrade $_indoperacionais = $_model->RetornaPerspectivas($_perspectiva);            que seria o erro nessa linha  Public function RetornaPerspectivas($_perspectiva){
   
       return $_perspectiva;
 
 }

Comment: Por que dar esse erro